# Redirect a specific address on a subdomain to the parent domain for Ajax purposes

Tags: apache, zend-framework, .htaccess

I want to redirect b.mydomain.com to mydomain.com/some/other/address with either Zend Framework or htaccess. The problem is, a page on b.mydomain.com needs to make an Ajax request to an address on mydomain.com. I know I can do this by transparently redirecting the request.

Internally, I'm using the  Zend Framework router to resolve requests to b.mydomain.com to its own controller.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this with chained routes.

```
<otherDomain type="Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Hostname">
    <route>b.mydomain</route>
    <chains>
        <bAjaxRequest type="Zend_Controller_Router_Route">
            <route>some/route</route>
            <defaults>
                <controller>somecontroller</controller>
                <action>someaction</action>
            </defaults>
        </bAjaxRequest>
    </chains>
</otherDomain>
```

With this Ajax requests to `b.mydomain/some/route` are successfully handled by `someaction` in `somecontroller`.